# mssql on ubuntu will not start, cannot update 404

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu

I did a routine Ubuntu system update for security patches today (2018-02-21)... mssql will no longer start or update, seeing failures in error log, systemctl and update output with 404 like:

```
Err:13 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
```

Problem: routine update breaks my vanilla Ubuntu 16 LTS with mssql-server instance. No other substantive info obvious to me looking in logs, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by guessing this was due to a server update and the source url changed. I added the current source per their instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu

This added the NEW source with a `sudo add-apt-repository ...` per the docs. I then manually comment-out (or you can remove) the old 404 source in [`/etc/apt/sources.list`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine).

Finally `sudo apt-get update -y ...` and start the server and I can again see it running (netstat or whatever to see the service up).

To be clear the URL changed:

from 
`https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server`

to `https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017`

Comment: adding '-2017' to sources, or changing sources for existing installations is highly likely to both break them and makes these sources look dated, possibly all goals driving the change. That sucks.

Comment: The version without the version is from pre-RTM. I don’t think they changed it to break you and make your life suck. They added version so that in 6 months or 9 months or 2 years or whenever, the server would know if you meant to retrieve SQL 2017 or SQL 2018/2019/whatever.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand without knowing more than my limited experience adding the version/nuance in the url "-2017" would be preferred from the beginning simply because it doesn't require a change in the future. I could be wrong for reasons I cannot currently see clearly.

Comment: It's software, made by humans. Humans are imperfect.